# webrtc delay_estimator.c ..how to choose the best delay?

Tags: webrtc

I have a question on this code.

It's the code for finding delay.
[image: It's the code for finding delay.]

in order to estimate the delay,
in my mind,I should find the largest value from the array `mean_bit_counts[]`, but in the picture, they choose the smallest one. So could you solve my problem? Thanks!

```
// Find |candidate_delay|, |value_best_candidate| and |value_worst_candidate|
// of |mean_bit_counts|.

for (i = 0; i < self->history_size; i++) {
   if (self->mean_bit_counts[i] < value_best_candidate) {
     value_best_candidate = self->mean_bit_counts[I];
     candidate_delay = I;
   }
   if (self->mean_bit_counts[i] > value_worst_candidate) {
     value_worst_candidate = self->mean_bit_counts[I];
   }
 }
 valley_depth = value_worst_candidate - value_best_candidate;
```

[image: paper]

Comment: If a delay has a fixed element and a variable element and you want the best estimate of the fixed element, the lowest value is the one you should use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still do not understand.That in the paper, for the different candidate delay, i will find the largest one. My understanding is like this, bit_counts can represent the correlation, in [0,history_size] to search for the largest mean_bit_counts of the corresponding value as a delay. So what do you mean by the  fixed element?